# JDBC Connection from another thread blocks access to query execute

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

I have game server with 2 threads, one main and one second. Database is mysql

Main thread responses for computing game situation and connecting players to server, it makes much small transactions to mysql.

Second thread calculates statistics by calling mysql procedure. It takes 10 seconds to calculate it.

Each thread uses its own Connection. But when I start stats calculation in second thread, main thread connection waits until calculation ends.
So that means even if I have 2 connections and 2 threads, one connection waits for another connection complete.

But when I start same procedure from web interface - no blocks appears at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

---

SOLVED

```
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("call updateScores();");
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) { }
    }
```

I have reduced execute method as possible and all locks disappeared! Above new code for stats calculator, below is old

```
public MySQLConnector(GameServer serv, String url, String user, String password) {

 /* */

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public int update(SQLRequest r) {
    //System.out.println("Executing query " + r.getRequest());
    int id = -1;
    Statement stmt = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        if (r.getParams() == null) {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(r.getRequest(), RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        } else {
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(r.getRequest(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            for (int i = 0; i < r.getParams().size(); i++) pstmt.setString(i + 1, r.getParams().get(i));
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        }

        if (rs.next())
            id = rs.getInt(1);

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) { /*can't do anything */ }
        if (pstmt != null) try { pstmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) { /*can't do anything */ }
        if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) { /*can't do anything */ }
    }
    return id;
}
```

In statistics thread:

```
class ScoreCalculator extends Thread {

SQLConnector db;

public ScoreCalculator(SQLConnector db) {
    this.db = db;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Slog.l("Scores calculation started");
    SQLRequest request = new SQLRequest("updateScores()");
    db.update(request);
    Slog.l("Scores calculation finished");
}

}
```

Between "Calculation started" and "Calculation ended" for example connections of new players stuck, because it is trying to get info from mysql and cant do it

Comment: Could you please show your source code? Maybe you have some `synchronize` blocks there?

Comment: @AleksandrPodkutin sure, I did. No synchronize blocks present. It is very simple wrap around connection and query execute

Comment: could you please post source code from main thread?

Comment: Where and how are you creating this object `db`? And could you please post part from main thread?

Comment: @AleksandrPodkutin it is much code fragmented in many classes. Main thing it is creates two `MySQLConnector` (which is wrap for jdbc Connection) in main thread and in second

Comment: ok, thank you. I would say, that you need to check `DriverManager.getConnection` method to be sure that it does not reuse the same connection and simply just waiting when previous thread will have released it. And the second you need to double check that you're not using the same `MySQLConnector ` for both parts.

Comment: Thank for your attention! Problem is solved, described in the post how

Comment: You are welcome! @AntNat